# Chrome loads very slowly while Safari very fast

Tags: safari, google-chrome, performance

Chrome loads any web page very slowly. Even making a google search takes more than 15 seconds while the same occurs in Safari instantaneously. I cleared the cache and disabled NPAPI plugins as described [here](http://www.zdnet.com/speeding-up-chrome-on-macs-7000008426/). But there was not a big change.

What might be the cause for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling?  Is this still an issue?