# How to decide which is the better browser for me: Google Chrome or Safari?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, performance

Consider that it is often said that...

1. Safari is [more battery/CPU efficient.](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-make-your-macbook-pro-battery-last-longer-6-tips/)
2. Most people will never run across a web site that runs better on Chrome than on Safari (excluding Google explicit sites).
3. Memory consumption is dramatically better with Safari vs Chrome
4. Excluding extensions that have security risks, Safari has a comparable list of available extensions.
5. Safari fares much better in terms of security. Google Chrome is comparable to user-installed malware.
6. Incredible developer tools like Instruments (just enable the "Develop" menu)

See [Chrome loads very slowly while Safari very fast](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116132/chrome-loads-very-slowly-while-safari-very-fast?rq=1)

[Safari vs. Chrome for Mac: 10 Reasons You Shouldn’t Use Chrome (2016)](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-reasons-shouldnt-use-chrome-macbook/)

In light of that I do not understand why anyone would want to run Chrome instead of Safari.

But browsers change a lot and often.
Websites with old opinions do not.

How do I find out if these assertions are really true for my current setup?

Comment: 3 things off the top of my head: much better ecosystem of extensions, cross-platform sync, developer tools

Comment: Unless you have a concrete problem or question with a *solveable* problem this is a question for MacInTouch.com not here.

Comment: @Steve I posted this question in response to the number of Chrome multi-process/performance questions. I've never visited MacInTouch.com, but I would like to understand why so many people insist on using something other than Apple's built-in browser, then ask why it runs so hot that it's melting through their lap.

Comment: Chrome is not my cuppa as well. But: As of v12 Safari has now no more *any* comparable extensions. // Apart from this half-answer: this seems very opinion driven as a Q and probably demands the same from As. To bring that a bit more into hard data, concrete problem: 1. reference your claims (many who?) 2. ask for facts, data?

Comment: @BillSmith - you might want to try and re-scope this Q so that it isn't so blatantly slanted as opinionated. I run Chrome and never have any issues w/ it on a multitude of MBPs w/ all variants of macOS. What you're saying just doesn't jive w/ my data points nor 100's of others that I've conversed w/ or worked w/ over the last 5+ yrs. BTW I run it w/ 350+ tabs daily. And no that isn't a typo 350+ tabs!

Comment: Questions asking for *OPINIONS* are considered off topic, this is not a discussion board, it's a place to help people fix their Mac problems.

Comment: I’m voting this +1 since I think we have a quorum of amazing people with opinions in the comments who I wish to hear their thoughts. Yes, this is subjective, but I think [with some references and light edits,  there’s a good subjective question](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3550/can-we-make-this-question-so-much-stronger-with-facts-and-references) since any good answer will have to explain _why_ someone would choose a less efficient browser that is also more capable to do X Y or Z. I’d love to have a place  to get answers that will illuminate choices in web browsers.

Comment: I‘ve put the question on hold now to prevent it from gathering further opinion-based answers. Please have a look at the Meta post linked in the comment above for how to improve the question to make it more fact-based and open for equally fact-based answers. Once edited it will be placed in the reopen review queue automatically.

Comment: It’s a little more nuanced @SteveChambers since there are good-subjective questions that we encourage.  This isn’t yet such a question without some substantial edits. As written, despite wanting to get it to the bar of “good-subjective” I agree with the hold for now.

Comment: My hope was to get some answers regarding what, exactly, people think they're gaining by using Chrome instead of Safari. I'm not looking for an opinion. I want to know WHY.

Comment: Since it's on hold and not collecting any more answers, please go ahead and close this question.

Comment: Asking for what people think is asking for opinions instead of facts, which is why the question is currently on hold. @bmike‘s post on Meta explains what needs to be edited into the question to focus on facts instead of opinions. As currently written the question invites answers which will debate the claims made in the question, which doesn’t help in answering it.

Comment: I tried to get this a bit into a better shape and direction. But I still haven't voted for RO, as this very likely needs another edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Chrome for work related stuff with its list of bookmarks etc

And Safari for personal stuff including banking

So if (and that is a big if) I let someone do a quick search on my machine at work then they are in chrome...

Nothing to do with memory use - and that is not an issue as my macbook pro is sufficiently powerful.